# Google Analytics for particular section on home page in swift 3

Tags: swift3, google-analytics, xcode8.2

I want to check user by Google Analytics for particular section or collection view cell data on home page in app .

But the problem is that I want to perform google analytics without clicking collection view cell or product shows on screen ,as the collection view cell shows on screen and it will automatically  notified that the cell or item is seen by the user . please help me to get some idea

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is on the Controller holding the TableView add this method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

and add the Google Analytics code there. You can also add some logic if there are only certain cell to track with Google Analytics.

Comment: Thanks Sebistas Sg for your suggestion

Comment: No problems mate, I just realized you wanted to use this in a collection view, the principle is exactly the same, the method to use:
`- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`